# iOS In App Purchase : hosted contents size limits?

Tags: ios, file, size, in-app-purchase

i need a confirmation about the file size of iOS apps which use the "In App Purchases" model. I gathered some informations after surfing for a pair of hours, even on StackOverflow, but i need to be sure about what i found (i am new at iOS development, please understand).

As for many coders out there, and expecially game developers, i have to take the installation package size into consideration. For my game, i suspect my graphics will require over 40 MB, but i'll try to stay under 50, to allow over-the-air download.

The ideal scenario would be :

-The user tests the game. Since the package is under 50 MB, he/she can download it without Wifi. Download and use of the game would be free (freemium);

-The user likes the game. 3 In-App-Purchase items are available : 2 related to a package which size is below 50 MB, and 1 which size is above (so Wifi only);

-The user can buy from everywhere (OTA) the 2 littler IAP items, and connect the iThing to Wifi and get, for a higher price, the larger one (order is irrelevant).

Long story made short, my questions are :

- I'm almost 100% sure about this, but not 100%, so please confirm : can i make Apple host the IAP files, instead than having to setup a different server and uploading the files on it ?
- I understand the app package can be 2GB, and that i have to keep it below 50MB to allow over-the-air download. But can i setup at least an IAP downloadable file which is over 50 MB ? (I suppose yes, but please confirm, it's crucial for my design; i didn't find this information at all)

Sorry if these questions sound silly but i'm in the design phase and knowing how much contents i can include in the game is very important for my next steps.
Thank you

Comment: personally, I never download apps over cellular. So I wouldn't be so concerned about it.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size for in-app purchase content hosted by Apple is the same as the maximum allowed size for apps, which is currently (as of 2015) 4 GB.

My app uses hosted content that's as high as 900 MB, and I haven't had any problems with files that size.  Of course, these are over the limit for downloading over cellular, but that's not a concern for my project.

Additionally, from Apple:

> Each developer account can create up to 10,000 in-app purchase
>   products across all the apps in the account.

Reference: https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devb57be10e7

Comment: 2 GB is for one app or for one Apple ID account?

Comment: It's 2 GB per in-app purchase. As far as I can tell, you can have as many in-app purchases as you want. I have over 300 in-app purchases for one app, and each one has a large package attached.

Comment: Please post a link to your resource, I would like to see if 2 GB is still up to date.

Comment: I can't find any official documentation about this from Apple, but I seem to remember that the maximum size for in-app purchase hosted content is the same as the maximum size for apps.  According to various sources, this size limit increased from 2 GB to 4 GB in 2015: https://9to5mac.com/2015/02/12/apple-increases-app-size-limit-4gb/

Comment: Thanks to the Wayback Machine, here's Apple's official press release about the increased app size: https://web.archive.org/web/20150310195816/https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02122015a